# Finding the limits of a triple integral.

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

Evaluate:

$$\iiint_V (x^2+y^2)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z,$$

where $V$ is the region in the positive octant bounded by the sphere $\|\vec{r}\|=a$.

I am unsure how to get the limits of integration here.

I believe I need to use cylindrical coordinates

$x = r\cos \theta$

$y = r\sin \theta$

$z=z$

$$\iiint_V f(x,y,z)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z = \iiint_V f(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta, z)r \:\mathrm{d}z\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta = \iiint_V r^3 \:\mathrm{d}z\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta,$$

But because the bound is only $\|\vec{r}\|=a$.. i'm unsure what to do now.

Or am i completely wrong :L?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boundary is a piece of a **sphere** so use **spherical** coordinates:

$$dV = r^2 \, \sin{\theta} \, dr \, d\theta \, d\phi$$

$$x^2+y^2=r^2 \sin^2{\theta}$$

Since we are in the first octant, the integral is

$$\int_0^a dr \, r^4 \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi$$

Comment: I am confused how to work that integral out.. do i do them separately or from right to left?

Comment: @Matt: since they are independent of each other, you may do them separately.  In general, work them right to left.

Comment: For each integration i got, $\frac{a^5}{5}$, $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ Do I now multiply them together? Also, with there being an a in the answer.. is that evaluated or do i need to go a step further?

Comment: @Matt: Looks OK to me.